# Joomla User Profile plugin, how to change the post url?

Tags: joomla

I'm using the user profile plug in for user registration form, but I need to change the url the form get posted to when submitted.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, the solution was to do a template override /html/com_users/registration/default.php and changing the action to some url specified in the template configuration:

```
action="<?php echo JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate(true)->params->get('myFormAction');
```

Answer (score 1):

The user profile plug-in is a core plug-in that extends com_user... it doesn't control the submission of the user registration form.

If you want to modify the user profile process, then the safest way to do it would be to make a copy of the user profile plug-in, rename the relevant sections to make it your own plug-in — you probably want to start with this [section on Plugins](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin).

By modifying your own copy you will be able to keep up-to-date with Joomla's security patches because you won't have modified a core file.

If you want to modify the registration process, you would need to override `com_user` before doing that though I would suggest you check the Joomla! Extension Directory (JED) first. There are a large number of extensions that modify the registration process, offer integration with other systems and extend the user profile already in existence.

Another tack might be to use one of the [forms extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms) that also handle user registrations — typically they allow you to create all sort of custom form including replacements for the standard user registration form. We've been very happy with a few of them and currently use [RSForm Pro!](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/4964) — it's a commercial product but extremely flexible and well supported for the small amount of cost involved.